# Splitting words in different lines to a list in Python

Tags: list, file-handling

I have a text file which has text as :

```
Hello All,

Hope you are enjoying learning Python
We have tried to cover every point in detail to avoid confusion
Happy Reading
```

I want to separate each word to a list in the following format,
['Hello','All,','Hope','you','are','enjoying','learning','Python','We','have','tried','to','cover','every','point','in','detail','to','avoid','confusion','Happy','Reading.
I have tried the below code which is working , but the only problem is the output is coming into double square brackets and in a new line as shown below

```
words = [open('example.txt').read().split()]
words
```

[['Hello',
'All,',
'Hope',
'you',
'are',
'enjoying',
'learning',
'Python',
'We',
'have',
'tried',
'to',
'cover',
'every',
'point',
'in',
'detail',
'to',
'avoid',
'confusion',
'Happy',
'Reading']]
I am new to python and learning . It would be of great help if someone can help me out. I want the output in single square bracket and in continuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words = open('example.txt').read().split()
print(words)
```

just remove the bracket.

or if you have to use the old code, you could use words[0].

Comment: and how to bring them in a same line ?

Comment: what do you mean, after the split, words is just a list of words.

Comment: do you mean print(words), then it is in same line

Comment: what does word[0] signify here?

Comment: yes print words in the  same line using end=' '

Comment: your original code put the split output into a list by the outside [], that's why you have to layers of []. words[0] is just selecting the only element in the list.